# Remover Linhas em branco num ficheiro Csv

Tags: php, csv

Eu tenho o seguinte ficheiro csv e gostaria de remover as linhas que estão em branco

Por exemplo

Ficheiro .csv

```
"C","C","X","123","asdsd","'232","'323","","323","23","4","dsa","dsad","dsa","ds","dsad","sdad,","24","0","11","4,2","fdf","","k","502","00","0035"," RAL","dgdf","R","12345","098765","321324",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"C","C","X","123","asdsd","'232","'323","","323","23","4","dsa","dsad","dsa","ds","dsad","sdad,","24","0","11","4,2","fdf","","k","502","00","0035"," GL","dgdf","R","12345","098765","321324",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"C","C","X","123","asdsd","'232","'323","","323","23","4","dsa","dsad","dsa","ds","dsad","sdad,","24","0","11","4,2","fdf","","k","502","00","0035"," G","dgdf","R","12345","098765","321324",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"C","C","X","123","asdsd","'232","'323","","323","23","4","dsa","dsad","dsa","ds","dsad","sdad,","24","0","11","4,2","fdf","","k","502","00","0035"," ERL","dgdf","R","12345","098765","321324",""
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

E queria remover as linhas em branco ou seja.

```
"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

Eu escrevi este codigo mas não esta a funcionar alguém me pode ajudar ?

```
     $or = fopen("output.csv", 'r'); 
     $nv = fopen("novo.csv", 'a+'); 
     $lines = fgetcsv($or, 5000, ",",'"');
     foreach ($lines as $line) {
         $csv = str_getcsv($line);
          if (count(array_filter($csv)) != 0) {
             fputcsv($nv, $line ,",",'"');
         }
     }
     fclose($or);
     fclose($nv);
 }
```

Comment: Qual o erro que seu código retorna?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faz da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$or = fopen("output.csv", 'r');
$nv = fopen("novo.csv", 'a+');

while (($line = fgetcsv($or, 5000)) !== false) {

  if (count(array_filter($line)) > 0) {
    fputcsv($nv, $line);
  }

}

fclose($or);
fclose($nv);
```

O erro que você está cometendo é que na linha `$lines = fgetcsv($or, 5000, ",",'"');`, está lendo uma linha só do arquivo output.csv, dessa forma o `foreach` está percorrendo os itens dessa linha, não cada linha do arquivo.

Comment: Não entendi, dentro da condicional, você está transformando as linhas vazias em array e contando os indices?

Comment: Não, as linhas onde todos os itens são formados por string vazia estão sendo reduzidos para um array com nenhum item, assim quando o array é contado com count é retornado 0, que dessa forma essa linha não é inserida no novo arquivo csv.

Comment: Bem simplista. Eu já estava aqui pensando em usar regex para fazer esse filtro kkk

Comment: 5* funciona perfeitamente.